# Why does my icon swap it's drop-down menu for another icon, instead of its own?

Tags: html, css

I created the document with HTML CSS and a little JavaScript
And the icons are inline flexed

I tried removing the icon the other icon swapped it's drop-down for and it worked just fine but one I put back that other icon into the documentation it swaps it again

Comment: Please provide more information in form of Code examples.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you put code into your question.